# Differential equation of a LRC circuit as Voltage output/voltage input?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, laplace-method

So in this presentation i have got, there is a LRC circuit, and they get this differential equation, but there is no procedure explained how they have got it. This is basicially a series LRC circuit because current I3 is zero, so it is the same current, and i think we can ignore Uc(0) in formula. Later when we would laplace transform final differential equation we would get transfer function Vo/Vi.

My question is how to get the final differential equation with Vo and Vi like this so i can get Vo/Vi, i searched the internet and couldn't find anything. English is not my first language so i couldn't express my self better.

In images input voltage(Vi) is Uu, and output voltage(Vo) is Ui.

[LRC circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSWG0.png)

[Differential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JeeG.png)

[Final Differential equation as Vo/Vi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yEFD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation obtains the time-$t$ potential difference drop $u_u(t)-u_c(0)$ following from the top left-hand corner to the point where the path through the inductor, resistor and capacitor meets the bottom line. In particular, with current $i_1$ through an inductor the drop is $L\dot{i}_1$, and the other terms take a current $i_2$ instead. The second equation does the same for the voltage drop in a path omitting the inductor. Since $u_i-u_u=-L\dot{i}_1$, $RC\dot{u}_i-RC\dot{u}_u=-LRC\ddot{i}_1$, so$$LC\ddot{u}_i+RC\dot{u}_i+u_i-u_u-RC\dot{u}_u=LC\left(\ddot{u}_i-R\ddot{i}_1-\frac{\dot{i}_1}{C}\right).$$But this vanishes by the second equation. Thus$$LC\ddot{u}_i+RC\dot{u}_i+u_i=RC\dot{u}_u+u_u,$$as desired. This arrangement has the advantage of placing the i/u terms on opposite sides, in differential operators analogous to the typical LRC equation $C\dot{V}=LC\ddot{i}+RC\dot{i}+i$.

Comment: Thanks man, i posted one more question for another circuit, i tried to do it like in this circuit and i couldn't get it. Link is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293925/differential-equation-of-a-rrc-circuit-as-voltage-output-voltage-input